# Roaming profile migration failed using Windows explorer manual copy

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I'm at the final stage of migrating an old demoted DC server, now I'm stuck in migrating/copying the roaming profiles of the users from the old win2k server (oldServer1) into the new win2k3 server (newServer1)

there are lots of profiles which points into the old server:

```
\\oldServer1\profiles\user1
\\oldServer1\profiles\user2
\\oldServer1\profiles\user3
.
.
.
\\oldServer1\profiles\userN
```

in the ProfilePath

I'd like to move it into:

```
\\newServer1\profiles\user1
\\newServer1\profiles\user2
\\newServer1\profiles\user3
.
.
.
\\newServer1\profiles\userN
```

I tried to copy paste from my DOMAIN\Administrator account but it is failed to copy ?
i cannot even browse inside the directory of user1 until userN ?
is there any fastest way to do the copy process rather than "taking ownership" for each of those directory one by one ? [hopefully by taking ownership the user will still be able to use their profile normally]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ntbackup` to make a backup, then copy that file and restore it on the new server. I know it's clunky old technology, but it uses shadow copy so it can get around permissions and certain types of "in use" files.

Comment: wow nice and simple Chris ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go ahead and clean up the permissions such that it was a clean permission inheritance hierarchy w/ "Administrators" having "Full Control" inheriting down through the directories (see [Using ICACLS to set permissions on user directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/43794/using-icacls-to-set-permissions-on-user-directories)). Then you can just copy the folder hierarchy.

As long as you've set the "Do not check for user ownership of Roaming Profile Folders" polichy setting to enabled Windows XP and newer client OS's won't "care" that the user's profile folder isn't "owned" by the user.

I've never bought into the idea of allowing the client OS to "provision" user profile directories, redirected folders, etc, itself. Having a world-writable folder on my server computers bothers me. Having a broken permission inheritance hierarchy bothers me even more. I provision user profile folders and redirected folders when I create the user accounts (via script, so that I don't have to remember to do it "by hand").