# User's home drive permissions don't contain system or administrators on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, windows, file-server, home-drive

I have a user whose home drive has only that user in the permissions. No administrators, etc.

I have tried to take ownership as a local administrator however I cant seem to apply settings to the child objects -- it still gives me a permission denied error.

I know there are some handy CLI utils that can redo permissions. Any ideas? Or even a way to do it through Windows?

The file server is a 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the GUI. You need to take ownership of the folder and subfolders (done on the "Ownership" tab of the "Advanced" security properties). Once you've done that, you can alter the permissions to your heart's content.

If you want to do it via CLI, look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/43794/using-icacls-to-set-permissions-on-user-directories/43845#43845) for a small example script.

Comment: I have already tried to take ownership and selected replace owner on subcontainers and objects but I still cant get access to the child folders and files. The administrator account has "special permissions" that are inherited from the parent.

Comment: Yeah I made an error. I got it working using default windows permissions.
I was selecting to only do it to this container not subcontainers.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you "have tried to take ownership as a local administrator" remotely? Do you mean that when you login locally as local administrator you cannot take ownership? Or you had tried to use domain administrator account? I believe you cannot do this unless local Administrators group on client machine had included domain admin account in itself

Answer (score 0):

FILEACL is a utility worth checking. It will let you look at inheritance, etc.

You can get it here:
http://www.gbordier.com/gbtools/fileacl.asp